# Django model for different models

Tags: django, django-models, django-views

I'm learning Django and I'm trying to make a sort of wiki type app. In this wiki there are different type of models: Characters, Items, Spells and Adventures. Each model has some fields that are the same (like name, author, date_created, etc.) and some that are unique to the model, like duration for adventures, alignment for characters, etc. The problem that I have is that if they are different models then every time I want to make something that is common to all of the models (like being able to like, favorite, create, edit, etc.) then I have to code for each model individually. Is there a way of creating a sort of Content model that contains every character, item, spell and adventure so that every time I want to make a form or a function I just make a Content form or Content function?

Here's some of the code, some parts are in spanish but I translated the important parts:

```
    class Character(models.Model):
    ALIGNMENT= (
        ('Legal Bueno', 'Legal Bueno'),
        ('Legal Neutral', 'Legal Neutral'),
        ('Legal Malvado', 'Legal Malvado'),
        ('Neutral Bueno', 'Neutral Bueno'),
        ('Neutral', 'Neutral'),
        ('Neutral Malvado', 'Neutral Malvado'),
        ('Caótico Bueno', 'Caótico Bueno'),
        ('Caótico Neutral', 'Caótico Neutral'),
        ('Caótico Malvado', 'Caótico Malvado')
    )

    name = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    author = models.ForeignKey(Usuario, null=True, on_delete=models.CASCADE, editable=False, related_name='personajes')
    alignment = models.CharField(max_length=50, choices=ALIGNMENT)
    description= models.CharField(max_length=200, null=True)
    likes = models.ManyToManyField(Usuario, blank=True, related_name='personaje_likes')
    favorites = models.ManyToManyField(Usuario, blank=True, related_name='personaje_favoritos')


class Item(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    author = models.ForeignKey(Usuario, null=True, on_delete=models.CASCADE, editable=False, related_name='items')
    description= models.CharField(max_length=200, null=True)
    likes = models.ManyToManyField(Usuario, blank=True, related_name='item_likes')
    favorites = models.ManyToManyField(Usuario, blank=True, related_name='item_favoritos')


class Spell(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    author = models.ForeignKey(Usuario, null=True, on_delete=models.CASCADE, editable=False, related_name='hechizos')
    description= models.CharField(max_length=200, null=True)
    likes = models.ManyToManyField(Usuario, blank=True, related_name='hechizo_likes')
    favorites = models.ManyToManyField(Usuario, blank=True, related_name='hechizo_favoritos')


class Adventure(models.Model):
    DURATION = (
        ('Corta', 'Corta'),
        ('Mediana', 'Mediana'),
        ('Larga', 'Larga')
    )

    name = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    author = models.ForeignKey(Usuario, null=True, on_delete=models.CASCADE, editable=False, related_name='aventuras')
    duration = models.CharField(max_length=50, choices=DURATION)
    description = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    likes = models.ManyToManyField(Usuario, blank=True, related_name='aventura_likes')
    favorites = models.ManyToManyField(Usuario, blank=True, related_name='aventura_favoritos')
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you can create a base model and then use a OneToOneField to this model in your other models.

```
class BaseContent(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=500)
    author= models.CharField(max_length=500)
    (...)

class Characters(models.Model):
    base_content = models.OneToOneField(BaseContent, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    (...)
```

Comment: Will that work for, say, creating forms? How would I make a creation or edit page using BaseContent for a character and for an item which have different fields?